# data doenst show on JSON format

Tags: reactjs, json

i'm learning react, in the middle of learning, i found new thing to store data using json document and run with json-server cli. the json was fine and running in localhost:3000/todos. here db.json document

```
{
  "todos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "bath",
      "done": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

the app was running fine [![enter image description here][1]][1]

and then i tried to use mysql database and convert to json using php. like this

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

 include("koneksi.php");

 
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM todos");

//data array
 $array=array();
 while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) $array[]=$data; 
 
 echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

it run well on localhost/db.php and give an output

```
[{"id":"1","title":"bath","done":"false"}]
```

but when i try to change json-server (localhost:3000/todos with php server(localhost:3000/db.php), the data doesn't show. i dont know how to fix it because it doesnt give error msg.

here todos app code

```
const TodoList = ({isRefresh, setRefresh}) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        // memanggil API untuk mengambil data todos
         if (isRefresh) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos")
          .then((res) => {
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            setRefresh(false)
            // ketika Rest API sukses, simpan data dari response ke dalam state lokal
            setTodos(data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setRefresh(false)
            if (err.name === "AbortError") {
              console.log("fetch aborted.");
            }
          });
       }
       
      }, [isRefresh, setRefresh]);
```

does the json output format have any effect on the results?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG0wK.png

Comment: Are you sure `localhost:3000/db.php` is right? by default this is the react port.